# Why does my microwave oven affecting Bluetooth signals?

Tags: interference, microwaves

Today morning I observed something interesting while I was listening to music with Bluetooth earphones. I connected earphones to my mobile phone that was lying almost 20 feet away . Music was of original quality until I turned on the microwave oven for heating up coffee. As soon as the oven was on , the audio was distorted and I could barely here anything from the earphones. The audio was back to original quality as soon as I turned off the oven .

To my curiosity , I took the phone near to oven , and did not observe the same distortion again .  Are weak Bluetooth signals usually effected by microwaves? I know Bluetooth usually operates around 2.5 GHz , and the operating frequency of oven varies based on brand. If there is some kind of interference of waves , why wasn't there any distortion when I had my phone near me ?

Comment: It was premature of me to ask this question before doing enough research , but this paper seems like has an answer. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1341691

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth signals share the same frequency band as microwave ovens. Microwave leakage from the oven can be picked up as if it were a bluetooth signal, and mess up the radio frequency amplifier and demodulation circuits of your bluetooth receiver, thereby screwing up the signal you want with extra stuff you do not want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: More importantly, what is the microwave oven trying to say to you?